# GIT: Subo los cambios pero no aparecen

Tags: git

El problema que tengo con el git es que quiero clonar el proyecto en otro ordenador y faltan varias clases `.cs`. Lo raro es que dichas clases aparecen pero con un triángulo amarillo y, cuando accedo a la carpeta donde he clonado el proyecto, no están.

Accedo al otro ordenador y

- realizo un cambio en esas clases y cuando quiero subir los cambios, me dice que no hay cambios pendientes;
- creo nuevas clases y me dice lo mismo, que no hay cambios;
- me voy al otro ordenador y tampoco me deja subir nada;

Pero sobre las clases que sí existen sí me deja modificar, he podido trabajar bien pero ahora ya no me deja, de tanto hacer `pull` and `push` el proyecto no compila. He tenido que crear una nueva rama a partir de la última versión y ya me compila, pero lo mismo: no puedo subir cambios.

¿Alguna idea de por qué puede ocurrir esto?

Uso windows 7, el repositorio no es público, y en el Visual Studio hago lo que siempre he hecho agrego elementos o modifico, me sale el check en color rojo indicando que hay cambios.
Cuando voy a Team Explorer y selecciono la opción cambios, me dice que no hay... a menos que los cambios se realicen sobre los elementos que si me puedo descargar.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos qué sistema operativo usas? ¿cliente de GIT? ¿órdenes introducidas y resultados obtenidos? Si es un repositorio público, ¿podrías facilitarnos la URL? Probablemente ese triángulo te esté avisando que esos archivos no están bajo el control de GIT, deberás agregarlos antes de hacer un nuevo commit, pero sin información adicional no puedo estar seguro.

Comment: Uso windows 7, el repositorio no es público. y en el Visual Studio hago lo que siempre he hecho agrego elementos o modifico, me sale el check en color rojo indicando que hay cambios.....cuando voy a Team Explorer y selecciono la opción cambios, me dice que no hay......a menos que los cambios se realicen sobre los elementos que si me puedo descargar.

Comment: Lo siento, no tengo experiencia con Team Explorer ni Windows 7, espero que otro compañero pueda ayudarte con su configuración/uso.

Comment: Gracias  por tu ayuda Oscar.

Comment: Haz un `git status` en un terminal en el folder de tu proyecto y dinos lo que pasa, no hay información que nos sirva actualmente...

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que el archivo este agregado en el proyecto con el tag `<Content Include=nombrefichero.cs>`

También podria ser que en las propiedades build action este marcado como none.

Answer (score 0):

El problema debe ser que dentro de la configuración del proyecto tengas referenciado un archivo `.cs` que no estas incluyendo en tu `commit`.

Los archivos de configuración de proyecto en Visual Studio son xml donde se declara todos los archivos.

Por ejemplo:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Logger.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">
      <AutoGen>false</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>false</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My\MyApplication.cs">
      <AutoGen>false</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>false</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My\MyComputer.cs">
      <AutoGen>false</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>false</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My\MySettings.cs">
      <AutoGen>false</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>false</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
```

Lo más seguro es **no** tengas el archivo en el sistema de archivos por ejemplo en `/ruta/Clase.cs` pero si está en la configuración, por eso te aparece ese mensaje.

Si los archivos están en una carpeta, puedes pulsar el botón derecho sobre la carpeta y seleccionar abrir carpeta en el explorador de archivos y ver cuales faltan, y agregarlos en el `commit` de tu equipo original para luego empujarlos al remoto.